# I have custom domain and firebase hosting, is it possible to take custom mail?

Tags: html-email, nodemailer, firebase-hosting, custom-domain

I have custom domain something like example-domain.com and I have Firebase hosting. Is it possible to take custom mail like info@example-domain.com and how can I use mail form in HTML with using Firebase hosting, thanks.

Comment: You will need an SMTP and IMAP email hosting. Once you have set up the proper MX records in your DNS, you should be able to send and receive emails with email clients and application forms.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Hosting only hosts static assets over HTTPS. It does not host your mailbox, you will need to look for another place for that.